# Between Condition is not working on server side

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, where-clause

Between Condition is not working on server side  
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where('("'.$start_date.'" BETWEEN start_date  AND end_date)', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->or_where('("'.$end_date.'" BETWEEN start_date  AND end_date)', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->group_end();

This Between Condition is working on local but not on server side

Answer (score 0):

maybe you database from server vs local doesn't have the same data, or maybe different format of dates to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Put this Condition

('SELECT `id`
FROM `bookings`
WHERE `id` = "'.$caretaker_id.'"
AND `booking_status` = "Active"
AND ((`booking_start_date` <= "'.$start_date.'"
AND `booking_end_date` >=  "'.$start_date.'")
OR (`booking_start_date` <=  "'.$end_date.'"
AND `booking_end_date` >=  "'.$end_date.'"));');